# jBPM6 - Deploy a process on jbpm-console

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jbpm

I have a web app and I want to use jBPM6 for process management.

I'm designing process on eclipse, and everything works fine, but now I want to see my process on Guvnor or the jBPM console but I can't deploy the process there...

I know this was possible on jBPM5, but I can't find a way to do it on 6... can you help me, please?

Comment: look at - http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_deploy_processes_in_jbpm_6
it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying the latest jbpm6 console ng or kie-wb?
If you are doing that you can copy the bpmn xml content and copy it inside the web process designer. You will be able to run it there.